# idProperty and replacing values - documentation

Tags: extjs, extjs6

If I add to a store a model which has the same value in the id property as another model in the same store, the old record is overwritten/replaced.

Where is this behaviour documented?

Is this behaviour supported/endorsed by ExtJS, or am I using a bug if I rely on this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is reflected by the core code of ext. When a record is added to a store if the id is present, and there is already a record with the same id, the record will be updated rather than added. You can rely on this behavior.